# What's the origin of the word 'noise' in photography?

Tags: etymology

I know we can also use the word grain which conveys the same meaning and which makes more sense in my opinion. But I noticed photographers have a preference for the term 'noise'.  What's got the word 'noise' to do with something that is visual not aural. Interestingly, same thing in French - the grain is called 'bruit' (noise).

A google search wasn't much helpful.

Also, is the term specific to digital photography (actually where I encountered the term) or film photography as well?

Any idea?

Comment: Actually, the word *grain* makes less literal sense now that most photography is digital.

Comment: My ears still hear noises and my eyes see grains even in the digital age!

Comment: @misensalem But it's not grain. Grain refers to the individual grains of crystalline material within the photographic film. In black and white film, each grain is either black or white, meaning that the image is composed of tiny dots; the dots are larger on more sensitive film, which is why you can see the textured appearance of "grain" in the image. Digital noise is a rather different phenomenon and, while it's not unreasonable to use the same word to describe both, you're not seeing "grains".

Comment: @David Richerby I heard some professional photographers use the terms alternately. Actually, it's a photographer who told me you can say either noise or grain referring to digital photography.

Comment: @David Richerby Oh, but your answer makes more sense, actually.

Comment: @DavidRicherby So a digital equivalent to "grain" is "pixelization"?

Comment: @Izkata Not quite. Because of the physics of the situation, film images are composed of an irregular arrangement of small dots, each of which is essentially "on" or "off", and the "grain" effect comes about because, on very sensitive films, these dots are big enough to see. Digital images are formed of a regular array of dots and each dot is "on" to some degree (corresponding to the brightness of that dot). Noise in digital images comes about by each dot having a random amount of brightness added to it by random processes, especially as signals get amplified.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(signal_processing)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise) the term is used by analogy to acoustic noise:

***Image noise***:

> - is an undesirable by-product of image capture that adds spurious and extraneous information.
> - The original meaning of "noise" was and remains "unwanted signal"; unwanted electrical fluctuations in signals received by AM radios caused audible acoustic noise ("static"). ***By analogy unwanted electrical fluctuations themselves came to be known as "noise".Image noise is, of course, inaudible.***

The expression "***image noise***" appears to have been used from the late 60's early 70's according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=image%20noise&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimage%20noise%3B%2Cc0).

Early usage example:

> - Some workers have judged gains over unaided photography in terms of the relative rates of photographic blackening. ***Image noise has often been ignored.*** Image resolution has either been quoted as an independent parameter, or it has been ....From [Advances in Electronic & Electron Physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=a9RG8gBd5eQC&pg=PA753&dq=%22image%20noise%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSsLLdle3JAhWCXA8KHcujA1MQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%22image%20noise%22&f=false)  1969.

[image] Noise clearly visible in an image from a digital camera

Comment: Also, in scientific photography, such as astronomy, the term noise is a technical term, which they use to precisely measure the signal-to-noise ratio, both in analog and digital photography. It can be measured and described accurately. It's simply a re-use of the technical term, without all the math, and not really a metaphor or borrowed term.

Comment: The original meaning of noise doesn't relate directly to AM radios. According to the Online Etymology Dictionary it's a 13th century word, and meant  "loud outcry, clamor, shouting,".

Comment: I'm familiar with the metaphorical meaning both in English and in French (noise in the sense of rumour), it's the technical meaning that is rather new to me.

Comment: Did you intentionally write "to be been used" or did you mean to write "to have been used" instead?

Comment: FWIW, it's not just scientific photography. It's digital photography (early scientific photography using large format films still used the word "grain"). The word noise specifically refers to the thermal/radio/electrical noise entering the system as the image signal travels down the wire to be captured. This is the meaning of "noise" in the signal-to-noise ratio sense. The term "signal-to-noise" was coined some time in the 1940s from the work of Claude Shanon et. el. at Bell Labs. They were trying to improve telephone networks but ended up with a general theory for data transmission.

Answer (score 6):

***Noise*** is a noun whose principal meaning relates to sound.

But it also has many extended meanings e.g. concerning scandal, rumour or report.

And it is used to express importance (Hoggett is now *a big noise* in the dental-supplies industry) and many other things.

But the extended use you are asking about relates to **sense 11a in the OED**.

> 11.a. **In scientific and technical use**: random or irregular fluctuations or disturbances which are not part of a signal (whether
> the result is audible or not), or which interfere with or obscure a
> signal; oscillations with a randomly fluctuating amplitude over a
> usually continuous range of frequencies. Also (in extended use):
> distortions or additions which interfere with the transfer of
> information.

Comment: OK. But how about photography and when did the term first start to get used in photography?

Comment: @misensalem Could you say what research you have done so far, please, so that I don't duplicate your own efforts.

Comment: No deep search so far; just a random google search but didn't find any info about the use of the word in photography. I'd be interested to know when did the term start to be used in photography. Also, is it specific to digital photography (actually where I encountered the term) or film photography as well?

Comment: It is specific to digital photography, as the 'noise' in question is signal noise, and the 'grain' is found on photographic film.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done!

Comment: @WS2 To be honest, I first heard of this other meaning to 'noise' only quite recently in digital photography. It sounded weird to me. But I thought it was specific to photography.

Comment: @RoaringFish there are noise sources that are specific to digital photography (digitisation noise, readout noise), but grain can be a noise source (as well as an equivalent to pixellation), and should be treated as such in quantitative work.

Comment: The origin of the word noise is in fact from the world of signal transmission.  the examples here are specious.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "noise" was non-existent in photography until the video/digital age.  Since much of the signal processing conundrums involves the introduction of "bad stuff" during transmission, and transmission is essentially a signals domain, the word "noise" stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It dates to the first use of electric signals to transmit images. Electrical transmission signal noise was already a thing by 1925 when the pursuit of television began in earnest. By 1930, electron scanning image tubes were pretty well developed. But their output produced a number of visual artifacts when converted back to an image. Collectively, these were noise. Noise reduction and sensitivity improvements were the focus of development from 1925 through 1970 or so,  and continued until 1990's in some areas. Direct charge-coupled devices began to replace the electron scanning camera technology around 1970.

It is not restricted to digital. But digitalization of image data is probably way older than you think as well. Stills were scanned and a value of 0-255 assigned to the pixel brightness, and then the data was shipped via digital diphase or some similar system, then reconstructed. Thus parity check and error correction was possible over the digital link.

[video camera tech circa 1930](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_camera_tube)
[image]

Comment: "High-speed" film (call it ASA 1600 or 3200 or whatever; now ISO) was and is inherently grainier than low-speed film because the actual silver crystals are *physically larger* at higher speeds than they are at lower ones, thus producing "grainier" final images. This grain looks somewhat different from the digital noise you get from boosting the gain through the roof during signal processing for digital images, but it is a sufficiently analogous concept that the two scenarios are sometimes inadvertently conflated or even deliberately grouped together.